# How to fire .next() for the second time in rxjs async subject?

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I have a component which has two buttons.when i click on the first button as per the demo in the given plunker below it emits an event and my service function emits an async subject with some values...When i click on another button i am trying to call .next event again but it is throwing some error...I have made a pluker demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/wpyV7o9JErdQMzGFZ4wp?p=preview ...If i use subject it works fine but i dont want to use subject in this case...

```
export class ErrorService{
  latestError:AsyncSubject<string> = new AsyncSubject();

  Save() {
    this.latestError.next('form submitted');
    this.latestError.complete();
  }

  Update(){
    this.latestError.next('form updated');
    this.latestError.complete();
  }
}
```

This is my service class and this is how i am calling .next event for async subject.

```
  this.service.latestError.subscribe(
err=> {
  console.log('result = '+err);
  this.result=err;
},
err => {
  console.log('err');
},
() => {
  console.log('complete');
});
```

And this is how i have subscribed the async subject...The click event works fine for the first time but when i click the another button it throws error.Somebody please help me to solve this error...How can i call .next() for second time using my async subject...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
this.service.latestError.subscribe(
err=> {
  this.service.latestError = new AsyncSubject(); // this set isStopped property to false again
  console.log('result = '+err);
  this.result=err;
},
err => {
  console.log('err');
},
() => {
  console.log('complete');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you call the `complete` method on the subject. It ends the data flow chain and you can't receive events anymore.

Comment: If i dont call the complete method it is not emitting any values even if i click button for first time...Is there any other alternative to emit data everytime .next() is called using async subject?

Comment: What is your use case? Is using the AsyncSubject class necessary?

Comment: Yea because i am loading a component dynamically using DCL and making a service call using the same button click event. if i use subject,by the time component is loaded the .next() statement is executed so it is compulsary for me to use async in my case